# Dynamic element reference in angular template driven forms

Tags: html, angular, angular6, angular2-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to generate form dynamically . I am trying to set element reference to ngModel dynamically but it is not working .

```
 #{{item.name}}="ngModel"
```

.Here is the code

```
  <input type={{item.type}} class={{item.className}} placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}"
  [(ngModel)]="item.value" name='{{item.name}}' #{{item.name}}="ngModel"
  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && item.value==''}" [required]="item.required">
```

Json

```
{
className: "form-control"
icon: "fa-font"
label: "TextBox"
layout: "row"
layoutList: (2) [{…}, {…}]
name: "textq6es58"
placeholder: "Enter your name"
required: true
toggle: true
type: "text"
}
```

Is there any way to set Dynamic element reference in angular template driven forms?

Comment: it's not neccesary. use simply `#item` I suppose your'e using in a *ngFor. Angular "create" a different template reference (really the reason is that Angular take account the scope, and the scope is different)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide it as

```
[id]='variableName'
```

so that the variableName will be the element reference ID.